# How can the Bene Geserit determine the sex of their offspring?

Tags: dune

Lady Jessica defied her Reverend Mother's edict to "bear only daughters" because Duke Leto wanted a son- but how could these women choose what gender their children would be in the first place?

Comment: It's to do with the way that they access their 'female' side and control their bodies.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Gender of Bene Gesserit offspring](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/27340/gender-of-bene-gesserit-offspring)

Comment: Much as the Bene Gesserit are able to neutralise the poison in the "water of life" by changing the molecular composition of it in their mouths into an antidote of sorts, then re-introducing that back into the source. They have perfected the ability to alter many of their bodily functions at a cellular level - thus, they can deny a child certain chromosomes.